# Best way for logging exceptions in Spring.NET with Log4net or nlog

Tags: exception, logging, aop, spring.net, aspects

I would like to know which way of log exception in [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) is prefered and why.
I found two common scenarios.

**1.Use IThrowAdvice.**

I created throws advice and in method AfterThrowing handle / log exception.

```
namespace Aspects
{
    public class ExLogThrowsAdvice : IThrowsAdvice
    {
        private ILog _logger;

        public ExLogThrowsAdvice()
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Error_file");
        }

        public void AfterThrowing(MethodInfo methodInfo,
            Object []args, Object target, Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

and use Common.Loggin API ([Common Loggin API](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/reference/html/ch01.html#d4e45)) for configuring for example [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for logging.

```
<sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging"/>
</sectionGroup>

<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
<log4net>
    <appender name="ErrorFileAppender"
              type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="errors.txt"/>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <levelMin value="ERROR" />
          <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date%newline%username%newline[%thread] %message %newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ERROR"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorFileAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

And last, create a proxy for the object in the businees layer.

```
  <!--ex log advice-->
  <object id="theExLogAdvice" type="Aspects.ExLogThrowsAdvice, ExceptionLogging"/>

  <!--auto proxy creator-->
  <object type="Spring.Aop.Framework.AutoProxy.TypeNameAutoProxyCreator, Spring.Aop">
      <property name="TypeNames" value="Aspects*"/>
      <property name="InterceptorNames">
          <list>
              <value>theExLogAdvice</value>
          </list>
      </property>
  </object>
```

This is first concept. The second which I found is to use aspect fo exception handling from the Spring Aspect library.

**2.Exception aspects from Spring.NET**

I would like create a handler for log exception and this handler will use the Log4net logger.

**Handler for exception:**

```
<object id="exLogHandler"
        type="Spring.Aspects.Exceptions.LogExceptionHandler, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="LogName" value="???"/>
    <property name="LogLevel" value="Error"/>
</object>
```

and then use this handler in exception handle advice:

```
<object id="exLogAspect"
      type="Spring.Aspects.Exceptions.ExceptionHandlerAdvice, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="ExceptionHandlerDictionary">
        <dictionary>
            <entry key="log" ref="exLogHandler"/>
        </dictionary>
    </property>

    <property name="ExceptionHandlers">
        <list>
            <value>on exception name SomeException log 'Ex:' + #e</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

I am not sure if second way is good. Maybe it is stupidity.

It is possible configure LogExceptionHandler to use the Log4net logger?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the *best*, but a [`SimpleLoggingAdvice`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-aspect-library.html#logging-aspect) logs exceptions for you. Furthermore, you can configure a `SimpleLoggingAdvice` to log execution time, method arguments and return values. Configuration looks like this ([from the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-aspect-library.html#logging-aspect)):

```xml
<object name="loggingAdvice" type="Spring.Aspects.Logging.SimpleLoggingAdvice, Spring.Aop">
  <property name="LogUniqueIdentifier" value="true"/>               
  <property name="LogExecutionTime"    value="true"/>               
  <property name="LogMethodArguments"  value="true"/>
  <property name="LogReturnValue"      value="true"/>

  <property name="Separator"           value=";"/>
  <property name="LogLevel"            value="Info"/>


  <property name="HideProxyTypeNames"  value="true"/>
  <property name="UseDynamicLogger"    value="true"/>
</object>
```

Of course, you still have to [configure a proxy factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167718/spring-net-aop-exceptionhandleradvice-doesnt-replace-custom-exception) and [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172623/how-to-configure-logging-in-spring-net-using-log4net), but you know how to do that already.